# Kendo UI datasource custom transport for supporting CORS in IE 8 and IE 9

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-web-api, kendo-ui, cors

Same Origin Policy (SOP) prevents Kendo jQuery-based controls from performing CRUD operations to an API (example: ASP.NET WebAPI) on a different domain. Our javascript front-end is on a different domain than the ASP.NET WebAPI that it communicates with over JSON. The solution we would like to use to get around the SOP limitation is to implement cross-origin resource sharing (CORS). However IE versions 8 and 9 support CORS through XDomainRequest instead of XMLHttpRequest.

George Durzi wrote a JavaScript transport function that uses the XDomainRequest object for IE and encapsulates $.ajax() for all other callers in [this blog article](http://georgedurzi.com/implementing-cross-browser-cors-support-for-asp-net-web-api/).

I would like to incorporate this javascript transport function into Kendo UI by creating a custom transport in the Kendo UI library.

Answer (score 1):

One way to do it is to patch jQuery by including [jquery.iecors.js](https://github.com/dkastner/jquery.iecors). Here is a blog post with more info: http://www.kendoui.com/blogs/teamblog/posts/11-10-03/using_cors_with_all_modern_browsers.aspx